# How to set the caret after the last character of a controlled input?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React component with a controlled input:

```js
class myComponent extends Component {
  toggleFocus() {
    this.setState({
      hasFocus: !this.state.hasFocus
    })
  }
  
  componentDidUpdate() {
    if (this.state.hasFocus) {
      this.input.setSelectionRange(1000,1000)
    }
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <input onFocus{::this.toggleFocus}
        value={this.state.myValue}
        onChange={::this.handleOnChange}
        ref={x => {this.input = x}} />
    )
  }
}
```

I use `hasFocus` state variable somewhere else in my code so I need the onFocus handler. I want to set the selectionRange after the component has finished rendering. I have tried doing this inside toggleFocus too.

Answer (score 1):

You should add `this.input.focus()` before `setSelectionRange`.

The [example](https://jsfiddle.net/836nz6cx/1/) using old `React.createClass` is following:

```
var App = React.createClass({
  getInitialState () {
    return {
      hasFocus: true,
      value: 'test'
    };
  },
  toggleFocus: function() {
    this.setState({
      hasFocus: !this.state.hasFocus
    })
  },
  onChange: function(event) {
    this.setState({
      value: event.target.value
    })
  },
  componentDidMount: function() {
    if (this.state.hasFocus) {
      this.setSelectionRange();
    }
  },
  componentDidUpdate: function() {
    if (this.state.hasFocus) {
      this.setSelectionRange();
    }
  },
  setSelectionRange: function() {
      this.input.focus();
      this.input.setSelectionRange(1000,1000);
  },
  render: function() {
    return <input onFocus={this.toggleFocus} onChange={this.onChange} value={this.state.value} ref={x => {this.input = x}}/>;
  }
});

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```

Comment: @FaureHu Sorry for the wrong url. Please check the example again to see if it works.